# UIScrollView not scrolling when touching some elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a UIScrollView with Autolayout on, and several elements on it. The problem is that when I try to scroll touching over some elements nothing happens, but when I try to scroll touching over some other elements the scrolling works perfectly.

The UIScrollView has several UIViews with UITextfields and UIButtons inside.

It seems that the touch events, or scrolling events, are not being sent to the parent UIScrollView, but just for some views.

Any thoughts?

Comment: please post a screenshot or some code

Comment: Why you don't use `UITableView` instead of `UIScrollView`? You don't need to worry about scrolling in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIScrollView` has a method `-(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view` that by default returns  YES if view is not a `UIControl` object; otherwise, it returns NO. So if you want to enable scrolling when touching `UIControl` objects you should subclass from `UIScrollView` and override `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:` to return always YES:

```
@interface MYScrollView : UIScrollView

@end

@implementation MYScrollView

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Indeed my friend, somewhere in the view hieratchy there was a view that wasn't a UIControl and disabeled the scrolling. The subclassing of UIScrollView solved the problem!